# Reset changes in git comes back

Tags: git, github

I cloned a git repo. I didn't make any changes on that repo locally, but when I run `git pull` this message shows up:

`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: ....`

I do `git reset --hard head` and I can see in Github Desktop app that the changes are reverted.

But when I run `git pull` again, the changes come back and I can see them in the Github Desktop again, and again the same message. What is wrong here ?

**Edit 1**

I ran git status and it shows up the same files as in Github Desktop. How can I just revert the changes. I didn't make these changes. I use two machines, these changes were made on the other machine, I added them there, committed them and pushed them to the online repo. I don't know why I see these changes here on this machine where I only pulled them.

**Edit 2**

This happens on mac and running git clean -f -d didn't help. The files are actually tracked but I cannot reset/revert them. – Arian Hosseinzadeh 4 hours ago.

Comment: Well, git thinks you changed the files locally. Have you run `git status` to see which files it thinks you have changed?

Comment: See what `git status` says. Sometimes this happens due to mode changes, or due to CRLF changes. (the mere existence of Windows causes pain for everybody)

Comment: Also, when you do `git status`, see if there's any untracked files that are currently in your branch that `git pull` is attempting to overwrite. If that's the case, `git reset --hard` won't remove those files for you, and you may be `pull`ing versions of those files that would overwrite the ones on your local machine. You can do `git clean -f -d` to get rid of untracked files and directories in your working copy.

Comment: I ran `git status` and it shows up the same files. How can I just revert the changes. I didn't make these changes. I use two machines, these changes were made on the other machine, I added them there, committed them and pushed them to the online repo. I don't know why I see these changes here on this machine where I only pulled them.

Comment: This happens on mac and running `git clean -f -d` didn't help. The files are actually tracked but I cannot reset/revert them.

Comment: you should be able to just do `git stash` that should conceal your changes then to delete them `git stash clear`

Comment: `git status` shows more than just filenames, it shows a summary of *what* changed. Try also `git diff` for a non-summary.

Comment: Given that you are on a Mac, you may be running into file name case issues. If the other computer is using a case-insensitive file system it might have, e.g., a directory `A` containing file `b`, and a *different* directory `a` containing *different* file `b`. Your Mac is simply unable to do this: it either overwrites `A/b` with `a/b` or overwrites `a/b` with `A/b`, because to the Mac, `A` and `a` are the *same* directory.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the changed files were `.class` files generated by eclipse. I stopped eclipse, deleted the local repo, cloned it once again, added the `target` directory to `.gitignore` and started eclipse after that. Finally, I pushed the change to the github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autostash true
```

Then a git pull should stash first any modified file, fetch, rebase any local commit on top of the (fetched) remote branch.

Check also what `git config core.autocrlf` returns: try and set it to false, then try again the `git pull`.